# What is source of "TabletPC inking error code. RtpEnabled called multiple times" error from within ArcMap?

Tags: arcobjects, .net, add-in

I am attempting to remotely troubleshoot an issue with an ArcMap AddIn (.NET 4) that I wrote where the users (only a couple of them) are receiving this error:

> TabletPC inking error code. RtpEnabled called multiple times
>   (Exception from HRESULT:0x80040239).

But I believe this exception is be thrown within a Stop Operation and that my AddIn is picking up the error.

Unfortunately, it is at a place in the code where I don't log the exception w/stack (*which I will fix in the next build*). This is occurring on only 2 machines that are both running 10.2.1. One is Windows 7 Pro and the other is Windows 8.1 Pro.

The issue is intermittent and recently resolved (temporarily) by clearing the users local profile. But the issue will return.

Has anyone seen this before within ArcMap and are there any known causes (ArcGIS Desktop itself, popular AddIns, extensions, specific system configs, user profile configs)?

As I am readying a new build with more logging, is there any diagnostic information that I can be collecting that would help isolate the cause if this error?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this problem? I've just encountered the same on a .NET 4.5.2 command line program.

Comment: I think flagging this as off-topic is a bit premature--none of the tech is obsolete.  10.2.1 reaches end of life in 7/2019.  I have customers using 10.2 to 10.5.1 and ever release in between (including the point releases).  Never mind the fact that solutions for a particular version of ArcMap may translate to solutions in newer versions--so don't necessarily buy the argument that it wouldn't help future readers.